# Update DataGrid Display From Stored Procedure And Complex Type

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

My scenario is very simplistic, I'm creating a data display using EF and SQL Server and have created a stored procedure which returns some display data to my ViewModel in the form of a complex type:

```
private IEnumerable<MyComplexType_Result> region1;
region1 = db.GetRegionalData(North).ToList();

public IEnumerable<MyComplexType_Result> Region1
{ get { return region1; } }
```

And in my XAML I bind the Region1 property to a datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PreTrainRegion1}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
...
</DataGrid>
```

This works but I also need the display to update if there are any changes made to the underlying database.  I have used INotifyPropertyChanged a bit recently but I'm not sure how to implement any kind of change notification in this particular scenario because the data is coming from a stored procedure call that occurs once when the application first opens.  Do I need to call the stored procedure on a timer to refresh the display data, set the ItemsSource to null and then back again, or what would be a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to call the stored procedure at a regular interval.

You can set the binding to TwoWay, but that will only keep track of changes to the object in memory. Since the DB is one more step removed, you'd have to make your call again.

Comment: I guess where I'm getting confused is how to do this from the ViewModel, or would this all have to be done through the code-behind?